# Sketching an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, vectors, random-matrices

Consider $a\in \mathbb R^n$ a random variable entries $a \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$ (Gaussian distribution with mean 1), i.i.d. elementwise.
Then 
$$
z = (a^Tu)^2 a^TCa
$$
is another random variable. I want to determine its mean, which I can then use to approximate $u^TCu$ via some concentration inequality.

Any ideas on how to find $\mathbb E[z]$ the expectation of $z$?

Comment: Expand the whole thing and use the fact that $Ea_ia_j=\delta_{ij}$.

Comment: Not sure it's that easy though; there are a lot of products with terms combining with $a$. Is it that easily separable?

Comment: Try to write down $Ea_i a_j a_k a_l$ for all choices of $i,j,k,l$. Unfortunately there is no shortcut to finding $Ez$.

Comment: Hmm, ok, I may take a different shortcut then to avoid the messines :) It seems so easy to compute $E[(a^Tu)^2]$, I was hoping the extra complication could be dealt with using some trick. Thanks for looking at it!

Comment: Maybe a typo: "$a∼\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ (Gaussian distribution with mean 1)"? should be mean 0, variance 1? The last theorem in [here](https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/165/) might be of help. EDIT: or maybe not since you have only a single random variable...anyway, it's good to know.